# Additional parameter for attached property

Tags: wpf, binding, attached-properties

I have an attached property. Can I pass an additional parameter in xaml via binding, and handle it in my attached property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attached properties do not handle things, they can have one value, if you need more than one value change its datatype to something more complex like a class or struct. Similarily a binding also only outputs one value, independent from what you pass in as parameter.